# Visual Studio 2015 / MVC 5: Attach to Process: Cannot obtain value of the local variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, attach-to-process

I can connect to the w3p process on my IIS box just fine. I can step through, although it seems to skip some areas. Also, when I try to view a variable value, I get:

```
Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.
```

[image]

I've seen MANY answer on this subject, but they all are geared toward local debugging. I am attaching to the server and getting this.

I have the source code and am working from that project. Does it matter if I publish the app to the server with the config set to 'Release'?
[image: release]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER: I switched it to 'debug' when publishing and now I can see the variables. I previously thought it was how it was set in the project properties, but it's how it's published to the server that makes the difference when publishing.